# React Admin - FileInput that uploads to a single flat key instead of an object

Tags: react-admin

In react admin, if you have a FileInput, it requires a child field, and stores the file URL inside the child field.  So for example

```
{
  "photo": {
    "url": "https://url-to-image.com"
  }
}
```

and the corresponding react admin code is

```
<FileInput source='photo' label='Photo' placeholder={<p>Drop your image file here</p>}>
        <ImageField source='url' title='title' />
</FileInput>
```

I want to upload to a single key called `photoUrl` instead of a nested object `photo.url`, which would look like this:

```
{
  "photoUrl": "https://url-to-image.com"
}
```

How can I do this?  When I omit the ImageField, I get an error that a single child is expected.  I tried leaving source="" empty for the imagefield but it still produces an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing parse and format functions to FileInput props

```
<FileInput 
    source='photoUrl' 
    label='Photo' 
    placeholder={<p>Drop your image file here</p>}
    parse={p => p.url}
    format={url => ({url})}
>
    <ImageField source='url' title='title' />
</FileInput>
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#transforming-input-value-tofrom-record